# T-SQL User-Defined Aggregates: same aggregate name with different types

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, clr, aggregate-functions

Can I create a custom aggregate with different types?

Example:

```
select Aggregate(cast(1 as tinyint)) -- Returns a tinyint value
select Aggregate(cast(1 as int)) -- Returns a int value
```

an so on...

Now I can do that changing the name of the aggregate: AggregateTinyInt, AggregateInt... but that variable is unreadable.